# Time trigger azure function with multiple event hub output bindings c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have a time triggered azure function, which conditionally sends data to three different event hubs, I tried defining this function as shown below,

```
[FunctionName("TTFunction")]
public async Task RunAsync(
    [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]
    [EventHub("EventHubName1", Connection = "EventHubConnection")] IAsyncCollector<string> eventHubName1,
    [EventHub("EventHubName2", Connection = "EventHubConnection")] IAsyncCollector<string> eventHubName2,
    [EventHub("EventHubName3", Connection = "EventHubConnection")] IAsyncCollector<string> eventHubName3)
{
    var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyEvent>("Some Data");

    if (1)
    {
      await eventHubName1.AddAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg));
    }
    else if (2)
    {
      await eventHubName2.AddAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg));
    }
    else if (3)
    {
      await eventHubName3.AddAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg));
    }
}
```

But it throws error error,
`Multiple bindings with name 'eventHubName1' discovered. Binding names must be unique.`

As per this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example), we can add one event hub return binding with time triggered function, but my requirement is to have three output event hubs.

This is my host.json file,

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "eventHubs": {
      "transportType": "amqpWebSockets"
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve that.

Comment: Could you please provide your `host.json` file code?

Comment: @PravallikaKV I just updated now in my question itself.

Comment: AFAIK, you can have multiple event hub return bindings with a time-triggered function. Try to change your function.json as shown in this [image](https://i.imgur.com/i2FrF1F.png) and check if it works.

Comment: @PravallikaKV https://i.imgur.com/i2FrF1F.png image is not accessible

Comment: Check in different browser if you can access.

Comment: @PravallikaKV I can access file now, but how this will work while executing my code locally? As I understand, when I build my function app, those bindings should be generated automatically from code.

Comment: This issue resolved, I have to add parameter  "TimerInfo myTimer",

[TimerTrigger("%ScheduleTriggerTime%")] TimerInfo myTimer,